# @State and @Published properties in child views, SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state

In *MyController*, I have the following property which is updated in other methods that are called:

```swift
@Published public var data = [Glucose]()
```

I also have a function, which limits this `Published` property by a given `limit`:

```swift
public func latestReadings(limit: Int = 5) -> [Glucose] {
        // return latests results
}
```

In a SwiftUI View, I consume this data by the following, which works fine and updates when `MyController`'s `data` changes:

```swift
    @EnvironmentObject var data: MyController

    var body: Some View {
        ForEach(self.data.latestReadings(limit: 11), id: \.self) {
            /// Display Text etc.
        }
    }
```

But, I want to call the following here, which converts the `Glucose` readings into a `DataPoint` array which the `Chart` consumes:

```
Chart(
    data: self.data.latestReadings(limit: 37),
    formattedBy: { (readings) -> [DataPoint] in
        var result = [DataPoint]()
        var i = 0
        for reading in readings {
            result.append(DataPoint(x: Double(i), y: reading.mmol))
                i += 1
            }
            return result
        }
    )
```

...Which refers to another SwiftUI View defined as:

```swift
struct Chart: View {
    // Properties
    @State var data: [DataPoint] // I asusme this should be @State
    var opt: ChartOptions
    
    // Formatters
    private var fmt: Formatting = Formatting.shared
    
    // Init
    public init(data: [Glucose], formattedBy:ChartDataFormatter) {
        _data = State(wrappedValue: formattedBy(data)) // Again I assume this is probably wrong..
    }

    ...draw views etc.
}
```

This all works on the first time the `Chart` is drawn, but the `data` property on the `Chart` view doesn't re-draw as the `MyController` `data` property changes. I assume I'm doing something wrong with state and observing changes here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your workflow correctly you don't need state wrapper in Chart, because it prevents value update... so try without it, like

```
struct Chart: View {
    // Properties
    var data: [DataPoint]

    // ... 
    
    // Init
    public init(data: [Glucose], formattedBy:ChartDataFormatter) {
        self.data = formattedBy(data)
    }

    // ...
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! You know, this is what I had tried the first time but I probablt just didn't wait long enough! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`@State` breaks the connection with your Controller. [Per the documentation `@State`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) should always be `private`.

Pass the `data` using `@EnvironmentObject` and manipulate it within the view or in the `Controller`.

Comment: Thank you. Looking into state more now! Cheers.